# Error "Insufficient result space to convert uniqueidentifier value to char."

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado, guid, uniqueidentifier

Table for the inserts:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CcureMessage] 
(
      [CcureMessageId] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
      [Event] [VARCHAR](20) NULL,
      [Type] [VARCHAR](20) NULL,
      [Message] [VARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
      [Xml] [VARCHAR](4000) NOT NULL,

      CONSTRAINT [PK_CcureMessage] 
          PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CcureMessageId] ASC)
                      WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)  ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CcureMessage] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_CcureMessage_CcureMessageId]  
        DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [CcureMessageId]
GO
```

I made the PK table have a default value so that I'm not passing a GUID at all, yet it seems I'm still getting an error related to the guid.

Insert command that works fine through SSMS:

```
INSERT INTO CcureMessage (Event, Type, Message, Xml) 
VALUES ('event 3', 'type 3', 'big json 3', 'xml-ish');
```

C# Code:

```
public void DoInsert(Message msg)
{
    // hard-coding this to set test values
    TopicMessage tm = new TopicMessage();
    tm.Event = "event 1";
    tm.Type = "Type 1";
    tm.Message = "json data message";
    tm.Xml = "xml data goes here";

    string connString = set to correct value;

    string sql = "INSERT INTO CcureMessage (Event, Type, Message, Xml) VALUES (@Event, @Type, @Message, @Xml)";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        SqlParameter eventParm = new SqlParameter("@Event", tm.CcureMessageId);
        SqlParameter typeParm = new SqlParameter("@Type", tm.Type);
        SqlParameter msgParm = new SqlParameter("@Message", tm.Message);
        SqlParameter xmlParm = new SqlParameter("@Xml", tm.Xml);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(eventParm);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(typeParm);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(msgParm);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(xmlParm);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Running this results in the error

> Insufficient result space to convert uniqueidentifier value to char

Comment: you have a typo ` SqlParameter eventParm = new SqlParameter("@Event", tm.Event);`

Comment: Updating. Thanks!

Comment: you are putting CcureMessageId into SqlParameter(@Event. See the post below for clarity

Comment: `new SqlParameter("@Event", tm.CcureMessageId)`

Comment: Yes, that silly mistake was the cause of the error. But, I still don't understand how putting the wrong value in the Event parameter leads to this error. My query maps the Event parm to the Event column. Can anyone explain why using the id value to on the event parameter causes this error?  Thanks

Comment: Your event column is defined as `[varchar](20)` - a uniqueidentifier requires `[varchar](36)`. And `tm.CcureMessageId` will still have the default value of `Guid.Empty` (`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`) even though you don't explicitly set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems that you are passing guid to a varchar column in your code

```
 SqlParameter eventParm = new SqlParameter("@Event", tm.CcureMessageId);
```

Should be:

```
SqlParameter eventParm = new SqlParameter("@Event", tm.Event);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wasn't working with guids in the C# code and received this error. So tracing this back to the stored proc, I found that the error came directly from there.

I traced it down to a conversion I was running on a GUID field as follows:

```
CONVERT(varchar(13), guid)
```

I assumed it would simply truncate the field value. So I had to do the following:

```
CONVERT(varchar(13), CONVERT(varchar(36), guid))
```